# Tiling a Rectangle by Squares - alternative proof

Tags: linear-algebra, irrational-numbers, tiling

This is a known problem about tiling a rectangle of $ 1 \times x $,$x$ is irrational with $n$ squares with length of their sides $s_1,s_2,\ldots , s_n$. You have to prov this is not possible. I want to try a proof similar but different than the one in [https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/stml-53-matousek-1.pdf](https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ematousek/stml-53-matousek-1.pdf) Miniature 12.

Proof by contradiction - lets assume that such tiling exists.
Let $ R/Q $ be a vector space of  the real numbers over the field of the rational numbers. Let $V$ be a subspace of  $ R/Q $ = $span\{1, x, s_1^2,s_2^2 \ldots ,s_n^2\} $  where $s_i$ is the length of the side of square $i$. Let $B = \{1, x, b_1,b_2 \ldots ,b_m\} $ be a basis for $V$.  We define a linear function  $f : V \to  V$  that satisfies $ f(1)=1, f(x)=-1,f(b_i) = b_i$. We clearly see that $nullity(f) = 1$ and $ 1+x $ is the only basis vector for the kernel of $f$.

We know that $x = \sum_{i=1}^n S_i^2 $. Apply $f$ to both sides and use the linearity of $f$ and have  $f(x) = -1 =  \sum_{i=1}^n f(S_i^2)$.
If  $S_i^2 \in Q$  then $f(S_i^2) \in Q $ because $f(1) = 1$. We can move all the rational terms $f(S_i^2)$  with $S_i^2\in Q$ to the left side and have $$ k= \sum_{ S_i^2 \not \in  Q} f(S_i^2)  $$ where $k$ a rational number.

$ f(x) = -1 \implies f(-kx)  = k = \sum_{ S_i^2 \not \in  Q} f(S_i^2) = f(\sum_{ S_i^2 \not \in  Q} S_i^2 ) $ and we get $$ \sum_{ S_i^2 \not \in  Q} S_i^2  = -kx + \alpha(1+x)  $$ for some $\alpha \in Q$ (recall that $f( \alpha(1+x))=0 $).

$x = \sum_{ S_i^2 \not \in  Q} S_i^2 + \sum_{ S_i^2 \in  Q} S_i^2  = \sum_{ S_i^2 \in  Q} S_i^2 -kx + \alpha (1+x)  \implies \sum_{ S_i^2 \in  Q} S_i^2 = x(1 + k - \alpha) - \alpha$

but this is impossible because $x(1 + k - \alpha) - \alpha $ is irrational and we got a contradiction.

I hope to get feedback on the validity of this proof.

Edit: This proof is invalid because, as noted below by Calvin if 1+k−α=0 then there is no contradiction. I wonder if there any elegant algebraic way to prove it. The proof idea in [https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/stml-53-matousek-1.pdf](https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ematousek/stml-53-matousek-1.pdf) is based on geometry (extending the edges of the squares ) and I wonder if there is a proof that is more algebraic.

Comment: What happens if $ 1 + k - \alpha = 0 $? If so, $ x ( 1 + k - \alpha) - \alpha = - \alpha$ is rational, so we won't get a contradiction then.

Comment: Since it is possible to "Represent an irrational number $x$ as the sum of perfect square $s_i ^2$ (EG $ \sqrt{2} = 1^2 + \sqrt{ \sqrt{2} - 1 }^2$), which tells us that a correct proof will need to incorporate the "2-D geometry aspect" somehow. Because your proof doesn't seem (at least to me) to use this aspect, it is most likely wrong. EG I could apply your proof to my equation to conclude that it is false, which gives a contradiction.